# .net core only works in Visual studio debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

We have an interesting issue where after upgrading to Visual studio 2017, a dotnet core application we have only works when using the build/debug feature in visual studio.

On clicking the arrow, the program successfully launches dotnet.exe and runs the program. If I use dotnet run, outside of visual studio, then dotnet.exe crashes and tries to open a debugger.

I have checked all versions (we are explicitly specifying the use of 1.1.1) and they are installed and correct.
I have attempted both x86 and x64.

Does anyone know what settings might exist that allow dotnet core to function only within visual studio but not when run independently?

Comment: can you share the csproj file?

Comment: dotnet.exe should run just fine outside of Visual Studio. You may  want to check and make sure you are calling the same version of dotnet.exe. To do this, go to Package Manager Console and type 'dotnet.exe --version'. Now, go to a command prompt and do the same. See if the versions match. Also, you may want to make sure you that all of the files being accessed by your application are being copied over to the appropriate locations. If you have any missing files, this could cause an issue. Without more information, I am just guessing at the problem, but these may give you a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for that, good tips! The version number is the same in both locations, and as to copying the files, though it doesn't work after a publish, it also doesn't work if I try to run it from the original location, which by definition must have all the files. Thanks for the help though, I'll keep digging!

Comment: I have the same problem. It runs fine in release or debug mode from VS2017. But when I publish and run from IIS it fails. It also runs in IIS Express from Visual Studio